# Plotting a Gradient Vector Field over the edges in Octave

Tags: octave

I want to compute the gradient of the edges and plot it as vectors in Octave, superposed to an existing image.

I applied a Sobel operator to get the edges. The vectors seems to be fine. But I would like to reduce my code as much as possible. And achieve same result with less steps.

I put some code here to be more clear. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
###########################################################################
#
# Get Panda picture
#
###########################################################################
C = imread ("C:\\Users\\Elizabeth Judith\\Desktop\\cesar\\panda.png");

###########################################################################
#
# Transform Panda picture from Colors to Gray
#
###########################################################################
G = 0.3*C(:,:,1) + 0.6*C(:,:,2) + 0.1*C(:,:,3);
imwrite(G,"C:\\Users\\Elizabeth Judith\\Desktop\\cesar\\panda_gray.png");

###########################################################################
#
# Gradient of Sobel
#
###########################################################################
Edge = edge(G,"sobel");
[gx,gy] = gradient(double(Edge));

indices = find(abs(gx)==0.5);
indices = indices(1:2:end); # To delete arrows
gx(indices) = NaN; 

indices = find(abs(gx)==0.5);
indices = indices(1:2:end); # To delete arrows
gx(indices) = NaN;

indices = find(abs(gx)==0.5);
indices = indices(1:2:end); # To delete arrows
gx(indices) = NaN;

indices = find(abs(gy)==0.5);
indices = indices(1:2:end); # To delete arrows
gy(indices) = NaN; 

indices = find(abs(gy)==0.5);
indices = indices(1:2:end); # To delete arrows
gy(indices) = NaN; 

indices = find(abs(gy)==0.5);
indices = indices(1:2:end); # To delete arrows
gy(indices) = NaN; 

###########################################################################
#
# plot gradient vectors over image
#
###########################################################################
figure;
imshow(G, []);
hold on;

###########################################################################
#
# Quiver of the gradient
#
###########################################################################
h1 = quiver(abs(gx),abs(gy));

###########################################################################
#
# To scale quiver arrows
#
###########################################################################
set(h1,'AutoScale','on', 'AutoScaleFactor', 15);
```

[Resultant Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVjsD.png)

Comment: So just to be clear, this code you have does work for you? It produces a correct output? Is there some specific improvement you're looking for then? Speed? If not why fewer steps? Clear code is often better than compact code if they do the same job, unless you have some other goal.  For speed you could try running the code profiler to see where it spends most of its time.

Comment: Also, it might be better to link a sample image so others can see what you're starting with.

Comment: The code works and it produces a correct output. But the way I deleted arrows looks complex to me. I wonder if there is a way to make it simpler. On the other hand, I am not allowed to embed images in my posts yet, so I have included a link instead (Resultant Image).

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to reduce the number of arrows that Quiver plots:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/306387

```
quiver(gx(1:2:end,1:2:end),gy(1:2:end,1:2:end))
```

Problem is that it will scale down the image because it is taking half of the gradient information. So probably you could scale the background image too and achieve similar result with less steps.

Best Regards

Comment: I see, this solution works with less steps. But as you mentioned it will scale down my vector image. Nevertheless, I can scale down the background image too and get similar result with less resolution. Probably good option if you don't care final resolution.